# How to display links inline in a div without spanning another row?

Tags: html, css

Hello guys am trying to make a couple of links inside a div to be displayed in a row so if the number of links exceeded the div width then a scrollbar can be used to navigate between the links but the problem is that the links never exceed the div width they always span a new row , I tried to use float and different display modes but doesn't work.

here is my code

```css
div {
  width: 500px;
  border: 1px solid gray;
  overflow-x: scroll;
  max-height: 50px;
}
div a.links {
  display: inline-block;
  background: lightgreen;
  height: 50px;
}
```

```html
<body>
  <div>
    <a href="#" class="links">link 1</a>
    <a href="#" class="links">link 2</a>
    <a href="#" class="links">link 3</a>
    <a href="#" class="links">link 4</a>
    <a href="#" class="links">link 5</a> 
    <a href="#" class="links">link 6</a>
    <a href="#" class="links">link 7</a>
    <a href="#" class="links">link 8</a>
    <a href="#" class="links">link 9</a>
    <a href="#" class="links">link 10</a>
    <a href="#" class="links">link 11</a>
    <a href="#" class="links">link 12</a>
    <a href="#" class="links">link 13</a>
    <a href="#" class="links">link 14</a>
    <a href="#" class="links">link 15</a>
  </div>

</body>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

One possible solution is to add (white-space: nowrap;) to your parent div.

Sample Code:

```css
div{
  width:500px;
  border: 1px solid gray;
  overflow-x: scroll;
  max-height: 50px;
  white-space: nowrap;
}

div a.links{
  display: inline-block;
  background: lightgreen;
  height: 50px;
}
```

```html
<body>
  <div>
    <a href="#" class="links">link 1</a>
    <a href="#" class="links">link 2</a>
    <a href="#" class="links">link 3</a>
    <a href="#" class="links">link 4</a>
    <a href="#" class="links">link 5</a>    
    <a href="#" class="links">link 6</a>
    <a href="#" class="links">link 7</a>
    <a href="#" class="links">link 8</a>
    <a href="#" class="links">link 9</a>
    <a href="#" class="links">link 10</a>
    <a href="#" class="links">link 11</a>
    <a href="#" class="links">link 12</a>
    <a href="#" class="links">link 13</a>
    <a href="#" class="links">link 14</a>
    <a href="#" class="links">link 15</a>
  </div>
</body>
```

Answer (score -2):

Try this

```
div {
border: 1px solid #808080;
max-height: 50px;
overflow-y: scroll;
width: 500px;
}
```